# Can I set the value of a column based on the value of another column in the SAME table using a trigger? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table (Table B) that receives all of its contents from a trigger on a different table (Table A). What I want to do is create another trigger inside table B that will insert a value into a column depending on the contents of another column in the table.

To put it in another way, I want the trigger to populate a row in the table with a hardcoded phrase like 'FREIGHT' whenever the contents of another column in the table match expected values.

The trigger I have now does work, but it inserts 'FREIGHT' into all of the 'AssignedTo' columns

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ComputeAssignment] 
ON [dbo].[BK_NotesRecord]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
begin

SET NOCOUNT ON 
UPDATE dbo.BK_NotesRecord

set AssignedTo =
case
when PartType IN ('300%', '400%', '412%', '434%', '435%')then 'FREIGHT'

end


end
```

Comment: Why not do that in the trigger you already have? If the value of a column is to be determined purely from other columns then maybe you need a *computed column* instead.

Comment: Sure, create a trigger on Table B that fires when a row is inserted into Table B with a value that matches your criteria in the other column.

Comment: @squillman I included some code above, do you know what error I might be encountering, or if I am going about this the correct way at all? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You need to match rows from `dbo.BK_NotesRecord` with rows from `inserted` which has a copy of the records that are being added to your table.  Have a read through the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Yes, that should be a computed column - also `in` doesn't work like that with wildcards.

Comment: @stu I am going to be displaying this data on a php local page, can a computed column be displayed the same way as a regular column for this task (if you are even aware, I know this is not the php forum)? Thanks for your help sir :p

Comment: You can `select` a computed column like any other column, if that's what you mean. Why not read the documentation on it and test?

Comment: @stu thanks stu that did it for me. I appreciate your help. I wish I could mark as answer

Comment: @BillyJDK Glad you got a solution. It's really a suggestion not what I'd consider a proper answer.